# GCP Cloud Run Runtime support schedule

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-run

I found this page for App Engine

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/lifecycle/support-schedule

Is it the same support for Cloud Run? If not, is there a separate support schedule page for Cloud Run?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Run support containers. There is no language dependency, end of life or stuff like that.

Some have run Cobols on Cloud Run, there is no issue with that!

---

Now, if you talk about the feature that help you to deploy your code on Cloud Run without building the container by yourselves, you have to know that the process is made in 2 time by the Gcloud CLI:

- Build a container with Cloud Build and Buildpacks
- Deploy the container on Cloud Run.

Therefore, again, Cloud Run is not impacted by this handy feature.

However, the fact is that Cloud Functions and App Engine also use Buildpack behind the scene before deploying the container on their respective service (and yes, all is container in the end!!)

You can find the Buildpack page on Google Cloud with language support [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/builders)
Anyway, you can find the Buildpack support on Google Cloud here

Comment: "Therefore, again, Cloud Run is not impacted by this handy feature."

What's that mean?

Comment: I am developing in .NET. The "Runtime support schedule" page shows .NET 8 and no .NET 7. The "Builders" page shows .NET 7 support but not .NET 8. Confused.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english. I mean that gcloud cli has a convenient feature to hide you the container creation and run, for you, a Cloud Build with Buildpack to build the container for you. But it's not a Cloud Run feature, it's a gcloud CLI feature. And therefore, it makes no sense to talk about language support and lifecycle with Cloud Run. At the end, it's Buildpack support that is important, not the runtime service. Replace Cloud Run, by Kubernetes and the way of thinking is the same!

Comment: App Engine has its own constraint. It use Buildpack to build a container, but it's possible that .NET7 is not supported on the service. The minimum is a support by Buildpack. But even if it's supported, the service (Cloud Functions, App Engine) can not support the language. Or it's a documentation bug (it's happen too!)

Comment: I was wondering if perhaps a doc bug - which is one reason that I mentioned it here.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Run doesn't have a support schedule similar to Google App Engine. In addition to @guillaumeblaquiere's answer, the nearest documentation available is [Cloud Run release notes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/release-notes) wherein it contains announcements about new or updated features, bug fixes, known issues, and deprecated functionality.

Also, according to the documentation on [Microsoft .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet):

> Standard Term Support (STS) releases have a shorter support period (18 months). Use STS if you want to try the latest features and a newer release is not available.
>
> The last 6 months of support before the release reaches the end of life. During the maintenance support period, .NET releases are updated to mitigate security vulnerabilities only.

You could still use .NET 7 for Cloud Run and other Google Cloud services that supports programming languages however it is recommended by Microsoft, the owner and creator of the .NET platform to use either .NET 6 or .NET 8 as they have longer terms of support, improve functional capabilities, and mitigate security vulnerabilities.

You may also check this documentation on [.NET 7 on Cloud Run](https://medium.com/google-cloud/net-7-on-cloud-run-d188c984681f) which is published by a developer advocate for Google Cloud.